# CLI Unification: Is there an 'sf' equivalent of 'sfdx' --dev-debug?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, cli, commandline

I run into an issue authenticating a Salesforce org with the new `sf` executable.
Using `sf login org -a myAlias` giving me an this error:

```
JsonParseError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

For `sfdx` it was possible, to display a more verbose output using `--dev-debug` at any command, which helps sometimes to get more information about an error.

Is there an equivalent of `--dev-debug` to the `sf` executable?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. After some time of debugging, I found that the
`C:\Users\{user}\.sf\sf.json` file was empty.

I removed the file and re-ran the `sf login` command, which recreated the file with environment information and fixed the issue.

I also found that the `.sf` folder contains a log file that did not contain a ton of information but could be useful in future situations.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I realize that this is not the answer to the question, but this post was the only reference I could find on this issue. If anyone else encounters the error message, there is a good chance that they will land here. Thanks